# Player's size in Roblox

Tags: lua, character, roblox

How to make it so all players have the same height in my Roblox game?
I watched some tutorials on youtube but it was too fast and didn't answer my question directly.

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/game-settings). There's a section for Avatar and their body scale. Alternatively, if you're scripting, you can set the [Humanoid's HipHeight](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Humanoid/HipHeight).

Answer (score 1):

You can go into game settings > avatar and change it there or you could make it change the height value upon CharacterAdded.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. In studio go to the Home tab click Game Settings (Your game has to be published), Click Avatar on the left, Scroll down and change to Scale setting so they only allow for what you need.

[image]